# Using Python as a speaker to intercept audio

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, python-sounddevice

I'm developing an app just for me which should act like a speaker in my Windows computer and record the data being sent to it.
Here's the code so far:

```
import soundcard as sc
import numpy


outputLib = sc.all_speakers()

speakers = outputLib[3]   

data = speakers.record(samplerate=48000, numframes=480000)

speakers.play(data/numpy.max(data), samplerate=48000)
```

but I don't think this makes sense because the outputLib class doesn't have a record function (I don't find) in the soundcard library.
Hopefully my questions makes sense.

Comment: A purely userland Python application can't act as a "virtual soundcard", if that's what you're going for.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to basically scrape sound from your soundcard? If so, you will have to write the record feature.

Comment: Yes, Essentially, I need to scrape the sound from my soundcard. Do you have any resources on how I'd go about that?